# "Andare a quel posto" vs "andare in quel posto"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have read the following sentence:

> Lei non vuole andare in quel posto.
>   (= She does not want to go to that place)

Is "andare a quel posto" also correct/usual?

Comment: _Andare a quel posto_ is not correct.

Comment: In fact, if you try to Google search "andare a un posto" you will find almost no results.

Comment: Is the same valid for other movement verbs ( eg "ritornare a quel posto") ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Andare a quel posto* does not sound correct and it is not usual.

Note that there are many places where you go *to*, e.g. cities, or places in a city:

- *andare a Roma*
- *andare a New York*
- *andare al cinema*
- *andare al mercato*

Sometimes it can depend on the place, e.g. compare *andare al mare* against *andare in montagna*. Other place names (e.g. regions, states, continents) require *in* instead (e.g. *andare in Toscana*, *andare in Canada*, *andare in Asia*).

With *posto* things might get tricky and depend on the exact meaning of it. For example, in a classroom every pupil has its own seat and desk, which is overall called a *posto*. In that case, a teacher might say *vai a posto* and it would be correct/usual. Moreover, *andare a posto* might also mean that something fits its place.

In the context of some generic place, though, *in* is used instead.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Grazie! Spero di non aver risposto "male", ad esempio non indicando riferimenti, ulteriori letture, ecc.