# Verbo tornare e le preposizioni

Tags: prepositions

Torno in ufficio

Torno a casa

Torno all'università

Torno dal dottore

Il verbo tornare seguito da una preposizioni mi ha sempre confuso, per caso esiste una regola grammaticale che spieghi quale preposizione devo usare dopo il verbo tornare?

Comment: “Tornare” funziona esattamente come “andare” e sulle preposizioni da usare con questo verbo, che effettivamente confondono abbastanza, ci sono già alcune domande: almeno [questa](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3639/when-to-use-andare-a-vs-andare-al-allo-alla-ai-agli-alle-vs-andare-in) e [questa](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10949/andare-a-quel-posto-vs-andare-in-quel-posto). Ti aiutano?

Comment: E anche [questa](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/5191) e [questa](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/10877).

Comment: Do all these posts answer your question?

Comment: Grazie per le vostre risposte.

Comment: Quindi, @gfleck, possiamo chiudere la domanda come duplicato? O hai bisogno di qualche altra informazione al riguardo?

Comment: Potete chiudere @Charo, grazie.